# Searching Users in Mongodb Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, express

I am using mongdb and have a database of users. I would like to allow users to search the database for other users based on their username. So far, I have tried and had no luck achieving this.

Here is my front-end HTML:

```
<h1>Search Users</h1>

<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="/users/search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="user_query" class="form-control" placeholder="Find Users By Username...">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```

And my server side code in app.js:

```
// Seach Page
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('searchusers');
});

// Search Processing
app.post('/users/search', function(req, res, next){
  var query = req.body.user_query;

  var result = db.users.findOne({"username":"user_query"})

  console.log('Searched for user: '+result);
});
```

My collection in the database that stores users is called "users". Whenever I call `db.users.findOne({"username":user_query})` I get an error after submitting the form looking like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
    at /Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/app.js:86:24
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/app.js:74:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/connect-flash/lib/flash.js:21:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:355:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/joshuablew/Desktop/MobiusApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

What can I do differently so that when a user searches a username in the form, the result will be shown on webpage? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like property `users` not defined in your `db` object. Does it work in other part of program?

Comment: This is the only part of the program that uses it at the moment. How can I define the users in my db object?

Comment: You need to extend your db object if you want to use that in such way. but as for me that is not a good idea

Comment: Alright, in your opinion what is the best way to do that? Since it's not the best idea

Comment: In my project I create separate CRUD MongoDB wrapper based on db object to operate only with one table. And then I use it like `users.findOne({"username":"user_query"})`;

Answer (score 0):

You should establish the connection to MongoDB first. You can found a guide for example [here](https://www.terlici.com/2015/04/03/mongodb-node-express.html).

In the `findOne` function you find the documents where the user name is "user_query". You have to substitute the proper name for proper results.

As an advice, you should use for example `user_name` instead of `user_query` for more readable code.

Comment: Yes, I have my mongodb connected in app.js with `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mobiusapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;`

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean when you say "proper name for proper results".

Comment: I mean "proper name" as the name of the user whom you are looking for. For example, for finding Alice you should write `db.users.findOne({"username": "Alice"})`.

Comment: Okay, yes that's what I'm after. But every query will be for a different username, which is why I inserted a variable where you have Alice, since the username being searched for will always be different.

Comment: Use `req.body.user_query` or an other variable instead of string literal which contains the user name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the db connection is setup successfully, can you check to see if the collection exists via the mongo shell?

A simple "db.users.find()" or "show collections" in the shell will show you whether the users collection exists or not. If it doesn't, you will need to create the collection via a db.createCollection("users")

Comment: I do have a collection named "users". Currently, it has 2 users for the sake of testing and development. I'm just having trouble accessing it and pulling specific users from the database

Answer (score 0):

I think your model name is User and the mongo automatically saves it in plural form I.e users.

Try this:

```
app.post('/users/search', async(req, res, next) => {
  var query = req.body.user_query;

  var result = await User.findOne({"username":query})

  console.log('Searched for user: '+result);
});
```